# How to write math equation from function to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, file-writing

I'm trying to stats from a file and calculate the mean,median,min and max. 
This much I've been able to do.

Where I'm struggling is I need to then give the user an option to save the computed stats to a new file. It's giving me an error that's saying 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Does anyone know how I could write my "computed_stats" function to a file?
I'd really appreciate any help!

Here is a screen shot of the bulk of my code. I didn't have enough screen space to include the table that prompts the user to enter selections or the function that loads data. They didn't seem important for this issue.

```
def table():
    print("Choose an option:")
    print("1. Load data")
    print("2. Display computed statistics")
    print("3. Save computed statistics")
    print("4. Exit")

def load_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for lines in f:
            numbers = lines.split()
            return(numbers)

def compute_stats(data_list):

    minimum = (min(data_list))
    maximum = (max(data_list))
    mean = (sum(data_list) / (len(data_list)))
    data = sorted(data_list)
    if (len(data) % 2) == 1:
        median = data[len(data) // 2]      
    else:
        median = (data[len(data) // 2] + data[len(data) // 2 - 1]) / 2
    return minimum, maximum, mean, median

def print_stats(data_list):
    minumum, maximum, mean, median = compute_stats(data_list)
    print(minimum)
    print(maximum)
    print(mean)
    print(median)


def save_stats(new_file):
    global comp_data    
    with open(new_file, 'w') as f:        
        f.close()



def main():


    selection = 0
    while selection != "4":
        table()
        selection = input("Choose a selection: ")
        print()

        if selection == "1":
            data_list = input("Enter the name of your file: ")
            data_list = load_data(data_list)
            data_list = [int(x) for x in data_list]
            print("Data read sucessfully \n")


        elif selection == "2":          
            print_stats(data_list)


        elif selection == "3":
            new_file = input("Enter File Name")
            save_stats(new_file)


main()
```

Comment: Show your code as text. A screenshot is not acceptable because it can't be copied and pasted into an editor for experimentation, among other things.

Comment: Add a plain Python tag in addition to Python-3.x

Comment: Images of code are useless here. I doubt you write your code using Paint. Most of us use code editors, which means the code is available as text. Please post your code here as text, copied and pasted directly from your code editor, and format it properly so that it's readable (and in the case of Python, properly indented).

Comment: Hey everyone. Sorry about that. I'm new to the site and posted this in a hurry before leaving for work. Just posted my code in there. I'm trying to get the the stats computed from the "Computed_stats" function to write to a new file. I feel like I need to return values from that but I'm not sure. I'm really struggling when it comes to passing information to different functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One classical problem that you have here is that you have mixed up presentation of the results with the computation. In your code, the `computed_stats` function does both the printing and the computing. By the way, it is badly named, something like `print_statistics` might be better. Often, when your function names don't naturally start with a verb, their responsibilities are badly defined.

For a very first change I would do something like this:

```
def compute_statistics(data_list):
    # Do whatever computations you need but don't print anything
    minimum = #Insert computation for minimum here
    maximum = #Insert computation for maximum here
    mean = #Insert computation for mean here
    median = #Insert computation for median here
    return minimum, maximum, mean, median # whatever statistics you are computing

def print_statistics(data_list):
    minimum, maximum, mean, median=compute_statistics(data_list)
    # Put your printing logic here using the results from above

def save_statistics(file_name, data_list):
    minimum, maximum, mean, median=compute_statistics(data_list)
    with open(file_name,'w') as outfile:
        file.write(f"min = {minimum}\n")
        # Put all your saving logic here
```

If you want the printed version to look exactly like the saved version, you might also add a function for generating that string, that you can call upon from `print_statistics` and `save_statistics`.

Later on, you might wish to think about how to better manage the state of your application so that you don't have to recompute statistics every time. But that is a story for another time.

Comment: Hey! 
Thanks allot for the tips. I'm completely new to this. I've had a feeling my functions were pretty poorly named so that's a big help. 

I tried setting it up the way you mentioned but when I end up running my print_statistics function it's saying that minimum,maximum..ect.. are not defined. 
any thoughts on this?

Comment: Hard to know without seeing your code. My guess would be that you forgot to assign the variables, either after calling compute_statistics (the first line in my print_statistics function) or within compute_statistics before returning (I will edit the answer to clarify).  The error message you are getting should somewhere show you a line number that points to where the variables were accessed but not defined.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that you edited your question. Your error is in the line `minumum,...=compute_stats`. It should be minimum. Please note that editing your question into a severely different one like you did should be avoided as now any answers to the original question may now appear completely off-topic

Comment: Sorry about the mix up there. I still have the original code saved if you would like I can change it back. Just wanted to check back before making any changes to avoid any further confusion. 

Also, I can't thank you enough for your advise here. It was extremely helpful!

Comment: nevermind, Just noticed you had edited your answer. 
Sorry if I made this a bit more difficult than it needed to be.
thanks again though!!